# Hide a slider's thumb in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

I'd like to make a slider's thumb (is that even the good word for this? I will assume it is) hidden for a short while before showing it again in javascript. Basically the idea is to not show it before the users clicks on the slider so as not to bias their answer.

For a MWE, I think this one is good one. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_rangeslider

In this one, by changing:

```
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

into

```
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
   width: 25px;
   height: 25px;
   background: #4CAF50;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: none;
}
```

I can make the slider's thumb disappear. But how would you make that happen in javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out you can't do this in JS directly. But an easy way is to use two different CSS classes and use JS to make the slider change class.

Here is a partial solution

```
    /* The slider itself */
.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;  /* Override default CSS styles */
    appearance: none;
    width: 25%; /* Full-width */
    height: 10px; /* Specified height */
    background: #d3d3d3; /* Grey background */
    outline: none; /* Remove outline */
    opacity: 0.7; /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
    -webkit-transition: .2s; /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

/* Mouse-over effects */
.slider:hover {
    opacity: 1; /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
}




/* The slider handle (use -webkit- (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) and -moz- (Firefox) to override default look) */ 
.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default look */
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
    height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
    background: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
    cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
    height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
    background: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
    cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}


/*An other class to make the thumb of the slider invisible*/
.slider2 {
    -webkit-appearance: none;  /* Override default CSS styles */
    appearance: none;
    width: 25%; /* Full-width */
    height: 10px; /* Specified height */
    background: #d3d3d3; /* Grey background */
    outline: none; /* Remove outline */
    opacity: 0.7; /* Set transparency (for mouse-over effects on hover) */
    -webkit-transition: .2s; /* 0.2 seconds transition on hover */
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

/* Mouse-over effects */
.slider2:hover {
    opacity: 1; /* Fully shown on mouse-over */
}




/* The slider handle (use -webkit- (Chrome, Opera, Safari, Edge) and -moz- (Firefox) to override default look) */ 
.slider2::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none; /* Override default look */
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
    height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
    background: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
    cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
    visibility: hidden;
}

.slider2::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px; /* Set a specific slider handle width */
    height: 25px; /* Slider handle height */
    background: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
    cursor: pointer; /* Cursor on hover */
}
```

Notice the `visibility: hidden;` for `slider2`.

Then use js to change the class like:

```
document.getElementbyId("slider").className = "slider2"
```